# How to sort(move) rows with columns by number included in items title

Tags: excel, excel-formula, columnsorting

I have bunch of rows with random ordered words. Some of them have numbers in the end. I need to order them by moving missing items into gaps, for example:

```
Column A        Column B       =>    Column A        Column B
Cat 1           Nice kitty     =>    Cat 1           Nice kitty 
Cat 2           Normal kitty   =>    Cat 2           Normal kitty 
Dog             Big Dog        =>    Cat 3           Mouse eater
Turtle 1        Old one        =>    Dog             Big Dog
Turtle 2        Young one      =>    Turtle 1        Old one 
Bird            Small          =>    Turtle 2        Young one 
Turtle 3        Dead           =>    Turtle 3        Dead
Cat 3           Mouse eater    =>    Bird            Small
Horse           Big            =>    Horse           Big
```

Comment: What do you mean with "moving missing items into gaps"? Just sort by column A and everything will be in alphabetical order, which will honor the numbers, but place Bird before Cat 1.

Comment: By "moving into gaps" i mean that - "Cat 3" is far away from "Cat 2" , so i mean that after "Cat 2" there is gap, which must be filled with that "Cat 3" which is at the bottom of table (at the moment).  And about ordering - the point is to hold order as it is, just to sort items as i showed above (without placing "Bird" before "Cat 1"). Actually the table is quite huge (1000 rows) and this is just small excerpt of it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i've solved it.

Solution - use custom sort list.
First I needed to split "Cat 1", "Cat 2" etc. into two columns - "Cat" and "1" , "Cat" and "2", then somewhere in other sheet remove Column A row duplicates. 
Then add all filtered(without duplicates) rows to custom sort list. And use that custom sort list to sort Column A.